# cannot enable fabric on Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to enable fabric on neo4j 4.1.3 enterprise but getting the below error.

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.dbms.database.DefaultSystemGraphInitializer@17fede14' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "The specified database 'fabric' already exists.".

```
#fabric config
fabric.database.name=fabric

fabric.graph.0.uri=neo4j://localhost:7687
fabric.graph.0.database=client1
fabric.graph.0.name=client1

fabric.graph.1.uri=neo4j://localhost:7687
fabric.graph.1.database=client2
fabric.graph.1.name=client2
```

Comment: It says the db fabric exists already, so remove it first.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted everything under /data and restarted and it seems to have resolved it.